# How can I make this multiple join MySQL query cleaner/with better performance?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build a search query for a site that I am working on that builds a list of recent/online players, the game(s) they are playing or want to play, which platform they are playing on, if they have a mic, their gamer tag/image for the platform and which game modes they want to play. The following query does that for me. However, it is very slow. I have made a cache for the data that lives for 1 minute.

<strike>Additionally, the `users_games_modes ugm` is joined on the `user_id` and not the `game_id` like I would like it to be. I don't know how I can get it to match on `game_id` also without moving `games_modes` before the join. If I move the join before how would I join the data on the results from the `ugm` join? (I hope that makes sense)</strike>

- Fixed this by using the `ou1.game_id`

I have indexes on each of the items in the where or join on statements.
The `ou1.stop` is dynamically added via PDO
Language used PHP and MySQL

```
SELECT
    ou1.id as oid,
    ou1.user_id,
    ou1.game_id as game_id,
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(ou1.comment, 1, 7), '...') as comment,
    users_systems.mic,
    users_gamernames.user_name,
    games.game_name,
    ou1.start,
    ou1.stop,
    ou1.system_id as system_id,
    (select value from users_settings where users_settings.user_id = ou1.user_id and users_settings.setting = 'display_name') as display_name,
    CASE
        WHEN ou1.system_id = '1' THEN 'xbox_tile'
        WHEN ou1.system_id = '2' THEN 'ps3_tile'
        WHEN ou1.system_id = '3' THEN 'steam_tile'
    END AS platform,
    (select value from users_settings where users_settings.user_id = ou1.user_id and users_settings.setting = platform) as platform_tile,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT gm.short_name ORDER BY gm.short_name SEPARATOR ', ') as modes
FROM online_users as ou1
LEFT JOIN online_users ou2 ON (ou1.user_id = ou2.user_id and ou1.id < ou2.id and ou1.stop < '2013-01-28 23:59:59')
LEFT JOIN users_gamernames ON (users_gamernames.user_id = ou1.user_id AND users_gamernames.system_id = ou1.system_id)
LEFT JOIN users_systems ON (ou1.user_id = users_systems.user_id AND ou1.system_id = users_systems.system_id)
LEFT JOIN users_games_modes ugm ON (ou1.user_id = ugm.user_id AND ugm.game_id = ou1.game_id)
LEFT JOIN games_modes gm ON (ugm.mode_id = gm.id AND ou1.game_id = ou1.game_id)
RIGHT JOIN games ON (ou1.game_id = games.id)
WHERE ou2.id IS NULL
AND ou1.id IS NOT NULL
AND ou1.stop<='2013-01-28 23:59:59'
GROUP BY ou1.system_id, ou1.user_id
ORDER BY ou1.stop ASC
LIMIT 50;
```

Here is the EXPLAIN output from sql-adminer:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6IDB.png

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6IDB.png]

games_modes index:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Opp.png

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Opp.png]

online users index:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcIEq.png

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcIEq.png]

users_games_modes index:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9Paq.png

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9Paq.png]

- Edit 1: removed 2 JOINs, added a CASE, and a subselect which removed a bit from the runtime and made it a little better for future updates.
- - a vast majority of the run time seems to come from the `users_games_modes` join. when i remove it, it goes from 16 seconds to 0.32 seconds. I have an index on the `user_id`. (i've attached a screenshot of the index for `users_games_modes`
- Edit 2: Added a `game_id` column to `users_games_modes` which lowered runtime from 16 seconds to 2.4 seconds.
- - Updated the index screenshot for `users_games_modes` [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9qoJ.png)

Comment: I think you should look at how you can improve the performance of your query. Show us some indexes.

Comment: i've added EXPLAIN and 2 indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        SELECT 
            ou1.id as oid,
            ou1.user_id,
            ou1.comment,
            users_systems.mic,
            users_gamernames.user_name,
            games.game_name,
            ou1.start,
            ou1.stop,
            ou1.system_id as system_id,
                (select value from users_settings where users_settings.user_id = ou1.user_id and users_settings.setting = 'display_name') as display_name,
                CASE
                    WHEN ou1.system_id = '1' THEN 'xbox_tile'
                    WHEN ou1.system_id = '2' THEN 'ps3_tile'
                    WHEN ou1.system_id = '3' THEN 'steam_tile'
                END AS platform,
                (select value from users_settings where users_settings.user_id = ou1.user_id and users_settings.setting = platform) as platform_tile,
                ugmt.modes
        FROM online_users as ou1
        LEFT JOIN users_gamernames ON (users_gamernames.user_id = ou1.user_id AND users_gamernames.system_id = ou1.system_id)
        LEFT JOIN users_systems ON (ou1.user_id = users_systems.user_id AND ou1.system_id = users_systems.system_id)
        LEFT JOIN users_games_modes_temp ugmt ON (ou1.user_id = ugmt.user_id AND ugmt.game_id = ou1.game_id)
        RIGHT JOIN games ON (ou1.game_id = games.id)
        WHERE ou1.expired=0
        AND ou1.start<='2013-01-04 21:47'
        AND ou1.stop>='2013-01-04 21:47'
        GROUP BY ou1.id
        ORDER BY ou1.stop DESC
        LIMIT 50;
```

I removed the LEFT JOIN and GROUP_CONCAT on `users_games_modes` and `games_modes` and changed the code in the tool that updates `users_games_modes` to update an entry in `users_games_modes_temp` on change.

This changed the overall query to go from 16 seconds to 0.002 seconds.

I assume the huge change in runtime was due to the join pulling the `users_games_modes` for all games for all users in the query for each line.